# Number from String LoadRunner

Tags: c, loadrunner

I want to extract set of digits from a string in loadrunner.
Eg: The order id 2385757 is generated.
We need 2385757 as an output.
The string can change..but there will be only 1 set of numbers which we need.
Can you please help me in getting that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service here. :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not display any effort from OP's side till time.

Answer (score 1):

**Correlation** is your path to extract data from information returned from the server.  If you need to capture a larger string and then cut it up then you can take advantage of all of the standard C language string manipulation functions.